# ¿Cómo hago para que imprimir el número y lista de los datos mayores que el promedio de un arreglo?

Tags: java

Estoy calculando el promedio de 5 valores almacenados en un arreglo. Quiero encontrar el número de datos mayores que el promedio y la lista de valores mayores que el promedio.

```
 public class prom {

    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double sumaNum = 0.0;
        double[] num = new double[5];

        for (int cont = 1; cont <= 5; cont++) {
            out.println("Digite un número real " + (cont + 1) + ":");
            num[cont] = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            out.println();
            sumaNum += num[cont];
        }
        double prom = sumaNum / 5.0;
        out.println("El promedio de los números es de: " + prom);
        double mayProm = 0;
        num > prom = mayProm;
        out.println("Numeros mayores que el promedio: " + mayProm + ":");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios fallos.

Primero los índices de los arrays (arreglos) van de 0 al tamaño -1.

Debes recorrer el array y mostrar los valores que cumplen la condición:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
double sumaNum = 0.0;
 double[] num = new double[5];
 for (int cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) { 
out.println("Digite un número real " + (cont + 1) + ":"); 
num[cont] = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
 out.println(); 
sumaNum += num[cont]; 
} 
double prom = sumaNum / 5.0;
out.println("El promedio de los números es de: " + prom);
 for (int cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) {
  if (num[cont] > prom){
out.println(num[cont]) ;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias Jose Maria! Ahora me sirve a la perfección!

Comment: Jose Maria, qué tal si a eso le quiero agregar que me cuente la cantidad de números mayores sin que me tire los números en sí?

Comment: En lugar de mostrar los valores incrementas un Contador.

Comment: int prom = sumaNum / 5;
        out.println("El promedio de los números es de: " + prom);
        for (int cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) {
            if (num[cont] > prom) {
                out.println("La lista de los de números mayores que el promedio es la siguiente" + num[cont] + ":");
                out.println("La lista de los de números mayores que el promedio es la siguiente" + [cont] + ":"); lo intenté así pero no lo logré